STM32 peripheral register access in C
I am programming an STM32WB55CGU6 with C and I am accessing the peripheral registers to light up an LED. However, the LED is not lighting up. My guess is that I'm not writing to memory/casting in the right way and it goes into HardFault, but I don't see where that problem is. I also did it in assembly and it worked, so shouldn't be a hardware issue. It compiles and uploads correctly. What's wrong with my code?
#include <stdlib.h>

#define CLOCK_ENABLE_GPIOBC 6
#define PIN_SET_PC15 1<<15
#define MODE_SELECT_PC15 1<<30
static int* RCC = (int*)0x58000000;
static int* GPIOA = (int*)0x48000000;
static int* GPIOB = (int*)0x48000400;
static int* GPIOC = (int*)0x48000800;
static int* GPIOD = (int*)0x48000C00;
static int* GPIOE = (int*)0x48001000;

int main(void)
{
    *(int*)((int)RCC + 0x04C) = CLOCK_ENABLE_GPIOBC;
        
    *GPIOC |= MODE_SELECT_PC15;
    
    *(int*)((int)GPIOC + 0x18) = PIN_SET_PC15;
    
    while(1)
    {}
    
}

I've gotten all of the memory addresses and the layouts of the registers from the reference manual.

Registers must be volatile.

STM has all the peripherals, registers, bit masks defined in its CMSIS package for each chip. Download and install per this stack overflow answer. There is no point of re-defining it yourself, and it can quickly become overwhelming and error-prone quickly.

The use of int and 1 << ... isn't helping, that's quite brittle code. Check out How to access a hardware register from firmware?

The problem was
*GPIOC |= MODE_SELECT_PC15

The reference manual shows that the reset value of GPIOC MODER register is 0xFFFF FFFF. When I apply bitwise or with 1<<15 to it, it changes nothing. For a pin to be in output mode, the corresponding bits have to be 01. When it is in reset state, all the of the bits are 1's.
